# pip コマンドで pyaudio をインストールしようとするとエラー finished with status 'error'

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter Notebook で `!pip install pyaudio` を実行すると以下のエラーが出るのですが、このエラーの解決方法はわかりますか？

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio: started
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio: finished with status 'error'
```

Comment: 使用しているOSとPythonの版数を追記してください。Windowsだと正式にはPython3.6まででしょう。[PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/), [PyAudio 0.2.11 Download files](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/#files), [conda-forge / packages / pyaudio 0.2.11](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyaudio), [PyAudio - Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

Comment: Ubuntu Linux で `pip3 install pyaudio` を実行してみると `portaudio.h` がインストールされていないので gcc によるコンパイルが失敗します。そちらの環境が同じ Ubuntu Linux であれば `sudo apt install portaudio19-dev` を実行すればよろしいかと思います。