# jupyternotebookでpyaudioを入れる方法について

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook

jupyternotebookでpyaudioを

!pip install pyaudio

このような形で入れたのですが
実際に使用してみると

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

このようになります。
バージョンが関係したりするのでしょうか。
解決方法を教えてほしいです。

Comment: 使っているOSとPythonの版数に依存するでしょう。Windowsだと正式にはPython3.6までの対応です。[PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/), [Download files - PyAudio - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/#files), [PyAudio - Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) Linux/Anacondaだとpipではなくcondaでインストールできるかも？[conda-forge / packages / pyaudio 0.2.11](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyaudio) なので`!pip install pyaudio`を実行して本当にインストール出来たのかを`!pip show pyaudio`とか`!pip list -l`とかで確認した方が良いのでは？

Comment: ちなみに[以前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/82734/26370)では`!pip install pyaudio`はエラーになっていたようですが、それは解決したのでしょうか？

Comment: !conda install pyaudioで実行してみるとかなり長い時間インストールし続けるのですがこういうものなのでしょうか。5分だとかそのようなレベルじゃありません。

Comment: それは何かおかしなことが起きていそうな雰囲気ですね。何かエラーメッセージ等は表示されないのでしょうか？ ちなみにpipで調べた時はインストールされていたのでしょうか？ またcondaを試したということはlinux-64bit系の環境なのでしょうか？ 動作させているPC/CPU装置種別・OSとその版数・Python版数・VM/Dockerの有無・Anaconda/Miniconda有無や版数・Jupyter版数・表示されたエラーメッセージの詳細などの情報を追記すると助言や回答が得られ易いかもしれません。

Comment: エラーメッセージは表示されていません。pipでやった時は以降でimportしたときにmoduleerrorが起きたのでできていないと思われます。私はAnaconda3上で行っています。エラーメッセージに関しては長いので以下に貼っておきます。anaconda3のpythonのバージョンは3.8.8でした。ノートPCでやっているので処理に限界があるかもしれません。

Comment: Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio: started
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio: finished with status 'error'　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　こちらがエラーになります

Comment: エラーメッセージに詳細な情報が無いので現象は不明ですが、PyAudioのソースにC言語のプログラムが含まれているのと、事前に(Pythonパッケージでは無い)PortAudioというライブラリがインストールされている必要があるようで、それらをコンパイル・リンクする開発環境(Cコンパイラ等)が揃っていないか、C言語ソースを含むPythonパッケージをビルド出来るような環境設定が行われていないといった場合が考えられます。それらを頑張って構築するか、類似の機能を持った他のパッケージ([Playing and Recording Sound in Python](https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/))に切り替えるか、OSをWindowsに切り替えて[Windows用の非公式なパッケージを配布しているサイト](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)からWheelを入手してインストールするといった方法が考えられます。

Comment: なるほど、分かりました。jupyterでこのままやるには時間がかかりそうです。実際にやってみるには時間がかかりそうですね。根本的解決にはなっていませんが今回はちょっとあきらめてpyaudioを使わない録音方法を実践してみます。ありがとうございました。